# Настроика формы html для отправки на url с параметром, который можно умножать на два

Tags: java, servlet

Нужна форма html, которая отправляет GET запрос на url например / hello с гэт-параметром value, принимающий толтко числовые значения например запрос /hello? value=5 вывод 10

Answer (score 0):

Если есть возможность редактировать обработчик формы, тогда в обработчике пишем

```
$newvalue=$_GET['value']*2;
```

Comment: Думаю, надо обратить внимание на тэг servlet